# Inline formset does not work only when the field is hidden in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm using inline formset and I can't submit the form when one of the fields is hidden in template.

```
{{ form.provider.as_hidden }}
```

When the field is shown in the forms of the formset everything works normally. The field is properly populated and I can submit the form.

```
{{ form.provider }}
```

Any ideas what causes this issue?

```
forms.py

class DurationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Duration
        fields = [
            'provider',
            'duration',
            'price'
        ]
        widgets={
            "duration":forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Duration'}),
            "price":forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Price'}),
            #"provider":forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the docs, `as_hidden` is only for bound fields and should be [primarily used internally](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#methods-of-boundfield). You should try using a a [`HiddenInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#hiddeninput) widget (or a [`MultipleHiddenInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.MultipleHiddenInput) widget if that's more appropriate for your `provider` field) and your form should work fine.

Comment: I tried HiddenInput widget already but without success. I am dynamically adding forms to formset (django-dynamic-formset.js). If {{ form.provider }} field has HiddenInput widget every extra added form prevents form submission. If default widget is present and {{ form.provider }} is shown in the form, field is normally populated in every extra added forms. When I added the extra form dynamically with HiddenInput widget for given field, then changed to default widget and just refreshed the page I noticed that field is not populated in extra added form.

Comment: What type of field is 'provider'

Comment: It's a ForeignKey field to another model.

Comment: Since I use Bootstrap I tried to add class ''hidden'' to {{ form.provider }} and now this field in all the extra forms is properly populated and I can submit the form. However I still find it strange that when HiddenInput widget is used submission does not work. I would like to solve this problem through Django not Bootstrap. What do you think of this?